# Prevent radiobutton click

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I have a win form, on which there are several radionbuttons and labels and some other controls wich I am generating at run time. Not what I want when I check a radiobutton, all the radionbutton should be unchecked except the one I checked. This applies to every radiobutton. In short, I want one radionbutton checked at a time.

```
 private RadioButton GenerateRadioButton(string id)
        {
            RadioButton _radioButton = new RadioButton();
            _radioButton.Location = new Point(32, 20);
            _radioButton.Margin = new Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            _radioButton.Size = new Size(130, 36);
            _radioButton.Name = id;
            _radioButton.AutoSize = true;
            _radioButton.Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            _radioButton.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(RadioButton_CheckedChanged);
            return _radioButton;
        }

  private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          HandleRadioButtinClick(((RadioButton)sender).Name);
            ((RadioButton)sender).Checked = true;
        }

     private void HandleRadioButtinClick(string ctrlId)
            {
                FrmSpace objFrmSpace = new FrmSpace();
                foreach (Control ctrl in pictureBox1.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is Panel)
                    {
                        foreach (Control ctl in ctrl.Controls)
                        {
                            if (ctl is RadioButton && ctl.Name != ctrlId)
                                ((RadioButton)ctl).Checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the code above. The problem with this code is that, when I check a radiobutton, if there is any other radiobutton that is checked, and I try to uncheck it, its checkedchanged event is also fired, that causes all the radiobutton unchecked again. I hope I am clear what I want to convey.

Please provide some solution.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you manually un-checking the radio buttons? Why don't you group them which will handle this part.

Comment: I would love to do that. But could you please tell, how to group them while generating them at run time?

Comment: While adding them to form add them to a group box instead to a form.

Comment: Like Jeremy has posted below.

Comment: Its not working with groupbox either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a [groupbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) for all of the radiobuttons? This is the default function you are asking for.

EDIT : to clarify your questions

```
        // some function
        GroupBox g = createGBox();
        this.Controls.Add(g);
        g.Controls.Add(radioButton1);
        g.Controls.Add(radioButton2);
    }

    public GroupBox createGBox()
    {
        GroupBox gBox = new GroupBox();
        gBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 105);
        gBox.Name = "BOX";
        gBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        gBox.Text = "This is a group box";
        return gBox;
    }
```

Comment: I have a picturebox, then I create panels at run time and add it to picture box. Then I create label and radiobutton then I add them in panel. Each panel has a set of one radiobutton and one label.

Comment: Groupbox will still be able to work. Just replace groupbox instead of the panel that holds the radiobuttons. Check out the link. Groupbox has a label built-in you can use too.

Comment: Is there any property for groupbox, that I need to setup. Actually its not working. Same result as panel.

Comment: Check the edit. Did you remove the event that you created for your radiobuttons? If this answer helped please mark as so.

Comment: Thanks alot. Not fully full filled my requirement but it helped. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put all `radiobuttons` into the same `GroupBox` control, which you can create at runtime too. In this case the expected behaviour should be handled by control itself, without need of coding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I take a groupbox at design time and add panels (containing radiobutton and labels) at run time to this groupbox . It will work?

Comment: Imo, no, you need GroupBox, like a prime parent. Why do you wan to use a Panel? Add directly to GroupBox.